# ruby-nmap how to create hash output instead of xml

Tags: ruby, xml, nmap, port-scanning

I want to use the [ruby-nmap](https://github.com/sophsec/ruby-nmap) gem to do a port scan on a number of instances. Here's what I'm currently using:

```
  Nmap::Program.scan do |nmap|

    nmap.syn_scan = true
    nmap.service_scan = true
    nmap.os_fingerprint = true
    nmap.xml = 'scan.xml'
    nmap.verbose = true

    # address[:public_ip] is my target
    nmap.targets = address[:public_ip]
  end
```

It creates an xml file, however I would prefer it gives me json or a hash as output and does not write this to a file.  Is there any easy way to do this without just reading the xml file it creates?

Comment: Maybe also ask this on the ruby-nmap github issues page?https://github.com/sophsec/ruby-nmap/issues

Comment: I just avoided using the ruby-nmap gem all together and just run nmap directly through shell instead.